# VSTS Visual Studio Build task is not incremental; keeps rebuilding

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

The VSTS msbuild task seems to keep executing `CoreCompile`, despite the `Clean` option being disabled and the source files untouched (nothing changed in the source fetch).

Yet locally when I run `msbuild` locally or directly on the build machine, it behaves as expected - all unmodified projects are not rebuilt; `CoreCompile` does not run `csc.exe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this was because the "TargetFrameworkMoniker" file that MSBuild generates and injects into the compile silently is written to the temporary directory, i.e. what you get when you run `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()`.

The VSTS agents however, specify their own temporary directory (`_temp`) and seem to clear it after every build. This seems like good behaviour - it's MSBuild that should fix it (IMO).

A quick and dirty fix, that *may* not work if your projects use mixed frameworks, is to add this MSBuild option:

```
/p:TargetFrameworkMonikerAssemblyAttributesPath=$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\temp.moniker.cs
```

Alternatively, you can disable the file generation with:

```
/p:GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute=False
```